# UK spouse visa priority service

Tags: uk-visa, family, nigerian-citizens

My wife lives in Nigeria and is applying for a spouse visa as I am British and live in the UK. She has been refused a UK visa in the past, but later got a tourist visa, which is still valid.

Will this prevent her from using the priority service?

Comment: There are actually two questions to consider. Even if she is permitted to use the priority service, it may not help much if her application requires additional processing time because of the prior refusal.

Comment: I can’t find a source at the moment but I’m pretty certain I’ve seen guidance on using the priority service that indicates applicants with any kind of adverse immigration history are advised not to use it (for the reason Patricia Shanahan suggests). I don’t recall seeing anything stating a previous refusal makes an applicant ineligible to use the service - I think that would be pretty nonsensical (because you still pay the extra fee regardless of how long the decision takes so UKVI has no incentive to ‘ban’ certain applicants from using priority).

Answer (score -1):

No, prior visa refusals won't disallow your wife to use the visa priority services.

Comment: Do you have a link to support this?

Comment: Downvoted for lack of citation or other evidence supporting the Answer's assertion.